# Populate field in db with another field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have table "Products" and want to populate one column with data from another column, that: `Product.first.product_id == Product.first.barcode`.
Currently keeping the barcode in `product_id` and `barcode` is nil.

edit: I want to populate all Products barcodes with existing data from Product.product_id.

I've been trying to google that, but still don't know how should I migrate the data. Thanks for any help!

edit: I use PostgreSQL.

Comment: which db you are using?

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ActiveRecord::Relation#update_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all), to update the existing records in the database. This can be executed from rails console or by using a [Custom rake task](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks).

```
Product.update_all("barcode = product_id")
```

For the future records, use a callback. In product.rb

```
before_save :update_barcode

def update_barcode
  self.barcode = self.product_id
end
```

Comment: you dont need `self`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

```
update Productsset set product_id=barcode
```

It's based on SQL.